# Can someone explain why Maya is renaming my models on import?

Tags: import, 3d, maya, maya-api

I am working with a large 3D modeled house dataset. Some of the prefabs in the house are conjoined for example all doors in house are a single prefab. When importing to Maya the prefabs are being broken up and renamed. I just need to keep the names the same or indexed. Help?

Comment: What format are the models being read from? Both the exporting application and the file format will impact what Maya sees on import.

Comment: The models that are being read in are obj files

Comment: OBJ is text based, the first thing to do is to open it up in a text editor and see what the obj is doing,  Different exporters will format their OBJs very differently